# $L^p$ integrability question

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, lp-spaces

The question is simply: If I have two random variables $X,Y \in \bigcap_{p\geq 1} L^p(\Omega)$ and a third $Z$ r.v. such that
$$XZ=Y$$
can I conclude that $Z\in \bigcap_{p\geq 1}L^p(\Omega)$?
(I know this would't hold for a single $L^p(\Omega)$ space, the point is that both $X$ and $Y$ are in all $L^p(\Omega)$, $p\geq 1$)

Or, in other words, if $X\neq 0$, $X\in \bigcap_{p\geq 1} L^p(\Omega)$ is then $1/X \in \bigcap_{p\geq 1} L^p(\Omega)$?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\Omega:=(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and $X(\omega):=\omega$. $X$ is bounded, hence in all the $L^p$ (as $\Omega$ has finite measure) but its reciprocal is not even integrable.